# How can I cache credentials in a Web Service?

Tags: windows, web-services, credentials

I have a REST web service running on a Windows 2003 Server.  I want to prompt my users from a  mobile app to enter their Windows domain credentials.  I want to send those credentials to the web service, and cache them for a few days.  It appears I can cache the credentials using the low-level [Credentials Management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#low_level_credentials_management_functions) but everything I've seen so far implies they're made to be called from an interactive session.  **What's the best way to cache these credentials in a web service?**

MORE INFO: The reason why I need to cache the credentials in the Web Service is because I need them to access some back-end resources (i.e. SQL Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351) provides a better mechanism to accomplish what I want.  I'll be looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't typically cache things in a web service.

How are you prompting them to enter their credentials to begin with?  That app / piece should cache the information.

Comment: I was leaning away from that, because I didn't want to continually send the username/password in clear text across the wire every time.  Most web services I've seen issue you a temporary token to use for authentication after logging in, so they must be caching credentials...

Comment: @GuyBehindtheGuy: You're right about the token.  They usually just store it in the db with a sliding expiration date.  Some sites use a permanent token for their API; others create it as part of an API token request.  Still, it is the client side that caches it.  When the token is passed the web service just validates that it is good prior to performing the action.